# How to prevent page reload on asp.net LinkButton OnClick function

Tags: c#, webforms, postback, linkbutton

I'm using the `<asp:LinkButton />`’s `OnClick` function on the server side to fetch data. I'm using `OnClientClick` to open a popup and populate data. But the page refreshes when I click the button. Please see the attached code and help me to fix the issue.

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit_Bill" runat="server" CssClass="lnkAddressButton" OnClientClick="javascript:ShowDialog_Both_New('Invoice','edit');" OnClick="lnkEdit_Bill_Click_new" >Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck. Also, pretty sure this has been asked before. Search.

Comment: Obviously i posted this after i got stuck, and my statement clears what the issue is, if you've any solution provide me, i've tried different solutions but all in vain :)

Comment: So do you want to open dialog first, then call `lnkEdit_Bill_Click_new` right?

Answer (score 2):

Google event.preventDefault(), I believe i've used that previously to prevent a postback.  Also remove the OnClick, if that's not what you want, and just use OnClientClick.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, if you don't want the postback, just fire the javascript. and you definitely don't need the server control. which you can present your code as below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowDialog_Both_New('Invoice','edit'); return false;">Edit</a>
```

Let's says if you still insist want to user ASP.NET server control of LinkButton, then you can do something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit_Bill" runat="server" CssClass="lnkAddressButton"
OnClientClick="ShowDialog_Both_New('Invoice','edit'); return false;" >
Edit
</asp:LinkButton>
```